# tsconfig generating a lots of errors

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, tsconfig

I now use VS2017 instead of VS2015 and I have a lot of trouble confining these.

I have configured a file named tsconfig.json when I do not use any TypeScript files.
I'm not sure if I configured it correctly.

> tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true, // These settings apply to .js files as well as .ts files
    "noEmit": true // Do not compile the JS (or TS) files in this project on build
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", // Don't include any JavaScript found under "node_modules"
    "bower_components", // Don't include any JavaScript found under "bower_components"
    "./Scripts"
  ],
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true // Enable automatic fetching of type definitions for .js libraries
  }
}
```

Now I find myself with a hundred errors all similar but not on the same file of this kind there:

> **Code** : TS6054
>
> **Description**   :
>   Le fichier
>   'C:/Users/haege/Source/Repos/Site_Internet_IDF8/Back_Office/Project_Readme.html'
>   possède une extension non prise en charge. Les seules extensions
>   prises en charge sont '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts', '.js', '.jsx'.
>
> **Projet** : Back_Office (Projet tsconfig)
>
> **Ligne** : 1
>
> **État de la suppression** : Actif

How to fix this problem?